# Is it possible to pass colModel to jQgrid from php backend?

Tags: php, jqgrid

Am trying to build a dynamic table. Where the backend holds the colModel and the table data.

For example:

```
colModel:[
            {
                name:'Forename',
                index:'forename',
                align: 'left'
            },
            {
                name:'Surname',
                index:'surname'
            },
            {
                name:'Date Of Birth',
                index:'dob',
                width: 80
            }
        ]
```

is on the front end but wanna be able to construct it via PHP.

Answer (score 1):

yes sure it's possible. You can use [Server Side Rendering](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/differences-static-generated-sites-server-side-rendered-apps/#:%7E:text=Server%2Dside%20rendering%20(SSR)%20is%20the%20process%20of%20rendering,the%20SPA%20framework%20to%20operate.) which allow you to print all values from the PHP Backend to your frontend.

I assumed you have native PHP project, then in your frontend side (in which have **.php** format file), you can make it like this:

```
<script>
//...your initiation for jqgrid
//here you can print some values from the backend side
colModel:[
        {
            name:'<?= $firstColName ?>',
            index:'<?= $firstColIndex ?>',
            align: '<?= $firstColAlign ?>'
        },
        {
            name:'<?= $secondColName ?>',
            index:'<?= $secondColIndex ?>'
        },
        {
            name:'<?= $thirdColName ?>',
            index:'<?= $thirdColIndex ?>',
            width: <?= $thirdColWidth ?>
        }
    ]
//...your initiation for jqgrid
</script>
```

Some of the variables should be available to the frontend side (maybe you have some MVC architecture or something, you can pass the data from the controller to the view)

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks but was thinking how to construct the model on backend and pass it as the colModel.

Comment: What do you mean about 'contruct the model on backend'?

Comment: Am talking about the colModel being created via PHP. So I know it would require an array of obects and the objects would contain the attributes required. Isnt there a way to pass it as an array onto the colModel?

Comment: yepp, but all the variables printed there is coming from the php backend (that you've passed in before).

Comment: That's true. Was thinking if it were possible to pass the job lot without doing it that way.

Comment: Did you mean the whole `colModel` configuration is generated from the PHP Backend? And on the frontend side, you can just print it out (as a single variable)?

Comment: Yes so the colModel on the front end recieves the array from the backend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232560/discussion-between-james-smith-and-alvian-kosim).